# How to find closer number of less than 400?

Tags: php

I want to nearest less than `400`. Means output will be `300`.

```
$a=200;

$b=300;

$c=400;

$d=500;

$e=600;

$f=700;

$arr=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f);
```

Comment: Is your array always sorted or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to find this value like this:

```
function nearest($array, $number) {

    rsort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a < $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array); // or return NULL;
}
```

Output(with the call `echo nearest($arr, 400)`):

```
300
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$checkingValue= 400;
$nearestVal = 0;
$arr=array(100,200,300,500);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if($val <= $checkingValue){
        $nearestVal = $val;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}

echo $nearestVal; //prints 300
```

Comment: @Asik `accept this as a answer` thats what we call: Reputation addicted

Comment: What do yo mean, So we don't ask to accept it or ask to upvote it if answer is correct means? Sorry, I want to know..I may not follow the rule which may defined by stackoverflow..please clarify..I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array_search()` instead of `loop`. Example:

```
$key = array_search (400, $arr);
echo isset($arr[$key - 1]) ? $arr[$key - 1] : 'Not found!';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=200;
$b=300;
$c=400;
$d=500;
$e=600;
$f=700;
$arr=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f);
$number=400;
$req_no=null;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($value<$number&&$req_no<$value) {//Checking if array element is less than 400 as well as greater than the previous result.
        $req_no=$value;
    }
}
//Checking if We Have got Any result.
if($req_no!=null){
    echo $req_no;
}else{
    echo "not Found";
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

a way with [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$val = 400;
$result = array_reduce($arr, function ($c,$i) use ($val) {
    return ($i<$val && $i>$c)? $i:$c;
});
```

Comment: Clearly OP is a newbie so its worth explaining what you have done above.

Comment: @Subhanker: you are right, I will add a link to the php manual.